# Diagram of a simple charge/discharge model of a battery powered by a solar panel with a DC motor load in Simulink

Tags: battery-charging, simulation, solar-energy, simulink, model

I want to simulate in Simulink a simple electrical system of the following nature: there is a battery powered by a solar panel and a DC motor load.

For example, during the day, the solar panel directly powers the motor and recharges the battery. During the night (during the period of low solar irradiation), energy is supplied to the motor from the battery.

First, I decided to look for diagrams that would implement this electrical system. I found just such a circuit, but in it the battery is, as it were, separated from the battery and does not feed on it.

[image]

https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/ijeeps-2019-0010/html

From the second diagram, we can take the idea of ​​switching depending on the state of charge of the battery.

[image]

https://www.mathworks.com/help/sps/ug/ni-mh-battery-model.html

There are many other circuits, but they are very intricate, aimed at exploring complex algorithms and complex power electronics devices. I only need to model the general principle of switching from solar panel to battery power.

**My considerations:** I would try something like this. In it, a battery is connected to the panel, which is recharged all the time and the load. When the insolation level drops below a certain level, the $S$ switch disconnects the battery, and the motor starts to be powered by the battery. Capacitor $C$ smoothes the voltage applied to the motor. This diagram is just the first thing that comes to mind. I do not rule out that there are better options. Here is what I want to understand. I ask for help and advice.

[image]

**EDIT:**

I would base it on something like this

[image]

Comment: In your hand-drawn schematic, the switch shorts everything out.  Also, do you have a specific question we can answer?

Comment: @evildemonic Yes, a shorting switch is an unnecessary item. I will try to formulate a more specific question (if necessary) after studying the answer proposed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first drawing is ideal: that topology lets you charge or discharge the battery in a controlled matter plus it lets the battery voltage be different from the load voltage and from the solar panel voltage. (Each of these devices wants to be at a different voltage.)

The second drawing is bad. It doesn't charge and it doesn't control the motor as it should.

The third drawing is sound, though somewhat inefficient. Just take out that switch across the battery because it causes a short circuit. Then it will work.

The fourth circuit is a meaningless jumble of unrelated parts. Toss it.

---

Regardless, make sure to add a motor controller between the bus voltage and the motor, otherwise you'll have problems when the motor starts or stalls. A motor controller also lets you adjust the motor speed and torque.

Comment: I liked your answer. It is well structured. 1. Yes, there are the necessary switches, and the converter after the battery is a controlled voltage divider. 2. Value of the 2 picture is that it shows how SOC can be used. This can be useful in the development of the control system. 3. This is an attempt to generalize most of the schemes used to solve problem into general principle. Switch is in the wrong position. 4. Shows that the battery is also a load. I put switch so as not to keep the battery in a state of charge all the time. As far as I know, battery is not constantly charged.

Comment: Another question that I would like to ask is: how to select a battery for a solar battery, what should be characteristics of charged/recharged battery, etc.?

Comment: _Another question that I would like to ask is_ ... start a new submission and ask _that_ question.

Comment: Is it necessary to create a separate question for this? I think it has something to do with this issue. If "docking" is difficult, then I can correct the question so that it can be supplemented with an extended answer. Is it good?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary: though it may be for the same product, the question is very different. It's not about serving you, it's about serving _others_, when they are looking for an answer for _their_ problem.

Comment: First, I will run some experiments with the model in order to frame the question more clearly. From this we will proceed further.